# Watching iTunes on KUbuntu 11.10

Tags: linux, itunes, kubuntu

I would like to watch Fareed Zakaria's show Global Public Square through iTunes.  Is that possible with Linux ( Kunbutun 11.10 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no. There is no iTunes version for Linux, and I doubt that iTunes would use a format that would let you copy the video to the Linux and play it. But, there is a (slim chance of succeeding) solution. If you run it on Wine, you might have a chance. Take a look at the Wine AppDB instructions [here](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=21302).